# Computing date and time for some altitude and azimuth at a determined location

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I have a code using astropy.coordinates (I've reproduced the same code with astroplan also) which give me the altitude and azimuth for a determined RA and DEC coordinates observed at a specific astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation .

Now, I want to do the inverse. I have the correct altitude and azimuth for a specific RA and DEC coordinates observed at a specific EarthLocation and want to compute the exact datetime which this occours.

A simple method would be to create a timeline of the altitude and azimuth of this RA and DEC coordinates and fit the curve to find the crossing point at the desired altitude and azimuth. But, I was wandering if there is some way to calculate this automatically without the curve fit.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SkyCoord.from_altaz()` function from the `astropy.coordinates` library to solve this problem. This function accepts altitudes and azimuth value, as well as the time and location of the observer, and returns a SkyCoord object that contains the equatorial coordinates (RA and DEC) of the object observed at the given time and location.

Here is a code example that demonstrates how to use this feature:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, EarthLocation, AltAz
from astropy.time import Time


ra = '10h42m57.6s'
dec = '-57d28m56s'
coords = SkyCoord(ra, dec)

location = EarthLocation(lat='30d43m17.5s', lon='-111d05m06.8s', height=2096)


time = Time('2021-03-15 21:00:00')


altaz = coords.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=time, location=location))

# Проверяем результаты
print('Height:', altaz.alt)
print('Azimuth:', altaz.az)
```

Comment: I want the date and time when the object is crossing a determined altitude and azimuth, not the object altitude and azimuth! I have the correct Alt and Az for the object. I want to discover the datetime it was observed!